# Hibernate: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: hibernate, persistence, one-to-many

I did see all other similar questions but none of the solutions solves my problem.

I have two classes: Person and PersonSynonym. A person can have many synonyms. The synonyms property in the Person class looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Set<PersonSynonym> synonyms = Sets.newHashSet();
```

and the PersonSynonym class:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
... (getters, setters, equals, hashcode, ...)
```

updating the Person objects works fine if I'm adding only ONE synonym to a person. As soon as I try to add a second synonym and try to update the person object I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [my.package.model.PersonSynonym#6]
```

the synonym with the id 6 is the one existing already. Apparently hibernate tries to insert the existing one again... why?

**Update:**

moving the JoinColumn to PersonSynonym doesn't help, Person:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person_id")
private Set<PersonSynonym> synonyms = Sets.newHashSet();
```

PersonSynonym:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private Long person_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Person person;
```

Comment: While it may not get to the root of the issue, have you tried different GenerationType strategies? Does the same error occur if you do?

Comment: I did, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `@JoinColumn` attribute is on the wrong side. It has to be in the `PersonSynonym` class with the member (probably `personId` or `getPersonId`) which references to the parent class.

Comment: Changing it doesn't help, updating person still triggers an insert. I've updated the question.